# How can I get the comments posted with like button?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I know how to get comments posted with a comment plugin, like this:

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time 
FROM comment WHERE object_id 
IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat  WHERE url ='THE SITE PAGE URL')
```

but it did not give me the comments posted with a like button.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: I havnt used facebook-api much but i'm pretty damn sure its somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but I can't find it. I have not understand the logic of facebook documentation yet.

Answer (score 2):

1- Get the page ID associated to the Like button

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_EXTERNAL_PAGE_URL
```

2- Query the feed connection of that page in order to get all the posts

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed
```

3- Filter the posts to get just the ones you made

Make sure you have granted the required permissions to perform both request.

You will be able to test these steps at:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: I can't get the PAGE_ID with https://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_EXTERNAL_PAGE_URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. I get this:
{
  "id": "MY_PAGE_URL",
  "shares": 49,
  "type": "link_stat"
}

Comment: When I do https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_URL/feed, I get this : {
  "id": "MY_PAGE_URL/feed",
  "type": "link_stat"
}

Comment: graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_EXTERNAL_PAGE_URL should provide you the page ID in the response, as well as the page name and other meta data. If not, it is because the node for that page has not been created still in the graph. To create that node, the admin for that page (fb:admin meta tag) should "like" the page, or it should lint that specific URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug (click on the Debug button)

Comment: Make sure you pass PAGE_ID/feed in your second request (PAGE_URL/feed will not work)

Comment: The debug tool tell me that "fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing." and "og:type is missing." I will fix it tomorrow. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have added the fb:admins, fb:app_id and og:type. And I got the PAGE_ID in the debug tool page. But when I do graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_ID/feed, I got this: {
  "error": {
    "message": "SETTINGS: Unrecognized pref_type 0 for NullProfileSettings pref name default_non_connection_tab.",
    "type": "Exception"
  }
}